# $f$, $g$ is measurable, then $fg$ is measurable.

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, measure-theory

I'm trying to show that, given $f$ and $g$ measurable, $fg$ is also measurable.

Is it true that

$$\{x : fg(x) > c\} = \left( \bigcup_{\substack{a,b \in \mathbb{Q}^+\\ ab \geq c}} \{x: f(x) > a \} \cap \{x : g(x) > b\} \right) \cup \left( \bigcup_{\substack{a \in \mathbb{Q}^-\\ b \in \mathbb{Q}^+ \\ ab \geq c}} \{x: f(x) < a \} \cap \{x : g(x) > b\} \right) \cup \left( \bigcup_{\substack{a \in \mathbb{Q}^+\\ b \in \mathbb{Q}^- \\ ab \geq c}} \{x: f(x) > a \} \cap \{x : g(x) < b\} \right) \cup \left( \bigcup_{\substack{a,b \in \mathbb{Q}^-\\ ab \geq c}} \{x: f(x) < a \} \cap \{x : g(x) < b\} \right)?$$

As of now I'm still trying to work through this problem, so hints, not answers would be appreciated, as well as if the above is correct. If the above is correct and there is a more compact way to write this, then I'd be happy to hear that as well.

Comment: $fg=\frac{(f+g)^2-(f-g)^2}{4}$, so it's enough to prove $f$ measurable implies $f^2$ measurable

Comment: @frank000 Yes indeed. Though this is a homework assignment and I'd already seen that proof prior, so I felt dishonest using it.

Comment: Why not first assume that both $f$ and $g$ are non-negative? This simplifies things a lot. (The claim follows then from the fact that the sum of measurable functions is measurable.)

Comment: @saz why is this assumption allowed? and how does it avoid frank's hint?

Comment: Well, okay; it depends on what you know about measurability. The standard trick is writing $f = f^+ - f^-$ where $f^+(x) := \max\{0,f(x)\}$ denotes the positive part of $f$ and $f^-(x) := - \min\{0,f(x)\}$ the negative part. Note that both $f^-$ and $f^+$ are non-negative measurable functions and $$f \cdot g   = f^+ \cdot g^+ - f^- \cdot g^+ - f^+ \cdot g^- + f^- \cdot g^-.$$

Comment: @saz Ah I see. Is it correct as I have written it?

Comment: If you know that measurable functions can be approximated by simple functions (aka elementary functions / step functions), then you can also prove the claim by showing that $f \cdot g$ is measurable for any two simple functions $f$ and $g$. And yes, what you have written is correct.